# Need help about python and number detection on string

Tags: python, python-2.7

I try to play a game (https://adventofcode.com).
The rules of the game is find the real first and last digit on each line.

Example:

> two1nine = 29
> eightwothree = 83
> abcone2threexyz = 13
> xtwone3four = 24
> 4nineeightseven2 = 42
> zoneight234 = 14
> 7pqrstsixteen = 76

And I decided to use python for decoding the puzzle with python, but I'm a beginner in python.

I have code who applied sucessfully the first day (on the game), but for day 2, I don't know how to convert number spelled out with letters: one, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, and nine to valid "digits".

The bug is cleary that I don't know to convert eightwothree => 83 and xtwone3four => 24 or zoneight234 => 14

Maybe using regex, but I don't know how to do... that's why I need help and advices.

---

```
def isInteger(s):
    try:
        int(s)
    except ValueError:
        return False
    else:
        return True

def main():
  # ASk user for the filename
  nomFichier = ""
  nomFichier = raw_input('Nom du fichier:')

  print "Opening file: " + nomFichier

  # Ouverture du fichier
  file1 = open(nomFichier, 'r')

  # les lignes sont lues et stored inside a variable
  Lines = file1.readlines()

  # if the first numeric has been detected
  firstValueDetected = 0

  lastValueDetected = 0

  firstValue = 0
  lastValue = 0
  countValue = 0
  count = 0
  totalLine = 0
  total = 0
  # Strips the newline character
  for line in Lines:
    count += 1
    print("Line{}: {}".format(count, line.strip()))

    firstValueDetected = 0
    lastValueDetected = 0
    countValue=0
    totalLine = 0

    tmp_string = line.strip()

    tmp_string = tmp_string.replace("nine", "9")
    print "convert: " + tmp_string

    tmp_string = tmp_string.replace("eight", "8")
    print "convert: " + tmp_string

    tmp_string = tmp_string.replace("seven", "7")
    print "convert: " + tmp_string

    tmp_string = tmp_string.replace("six", "6")
    print "convert: " + tmp_string

    tmp_string = tmp_string.replace("five", "5")
    print "convert: " + tmp_string

    tmp_string = tmp_string.replace("four", "4")
    print "convert: " + tmp_string

    tmp_string = tmp_string.replace("three", "3")
    print "convert: " + tmp_string

    tmp_string = tmp_string.replace("two", "2")
    print "convert: " + tmp_string

    tmp_string = tmp_string.replace("one", "1")
    print "convert: " + tmp_string

    a_string = tmp_string

    for letter in a_string:
      print letter
      if isInteger(letter):
        print letter +" is numeric :-) "
        if firstValueDetected == 0:
          firstValue = int(letter)
          firstValueDetected = 1
        else:
          lastValue = int(letter)
        countValue = countValue +1

    if countValue == 1:
      lastValue = firstValue;

    totalLine = firstValue*10 + lastValue
    print "First Value is " + str(firstValue) + " and Last value is " + str(lastValue) + " => " + str(totalLine);
    total = total + totalLine

  # Closing files
  file1.close()

  print "Total : " + str(total)

main()
```

---

Comment: Why are you using Python 2.7? That was made obsolete many years ago. Also, you've formatted your code as a quote. It's actually a lot of effort for someone to undo that and format it properly once you've lost the formatting - please [edit] your question

Comment: I use python 2.7 because is the version installed on my distribution.

Comment: Please explain the rules, don't make us read the challenge. For example, what happens when there's an actual digit, should it be ignored? What's the rule for overlapping numbers? And why `zoneight234` should produce `14`?

Comment: What distribution are you using that doesn't also have (or have the option to install) Python 3?

Comment: Debian 11... but I'm just exploring python, I don't pretend to be a python dev.

Comment: In `zoneight234`, your code would replace 'eight' by '8', ignoring 'one'. You can't just replace like this, you have to parse the line from the beginning.It's easy with a regex and `re.findall`. Without regex, a way would be to use `find` and `rfind` on all digits and numbers, and look for the one with the smallest/largest index...

Answer (score 0):

There is a python package which helps in this case.
[word2number](https://pypi.org/project/word2number/)

```
from word2number import w2n

def words_to_digits(value):
    try:
        number = w2n.word_to_num(value)
        return number
    except ValueError:
        return None
```

Example:

```
>>> words_to_digits("eighty three")
83
```